# What is time format of $this->db->query_times array in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, time, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Surprisingly there is no documentation of it for both codeigniter v2 and v3. I just found out the code myself from a tutorial here is the [link](http://sajanmaharjan.com.np/2013/02/05/code-igniter-log-all-queries/). The tutorial is not perfect and also not working but I tend to improve that.

What I'm referring is *$this->db->query_times* and *$this->db->queries*. And I'm amazed to found out that these are working.

Now you can use these in Codginiter hooks to determine which query is executed by using *$this->db->queries* and how much time it is taking by using *$this->db->query_times* and implement the hook after post controller

The result of *$this->db->queries* in codeigniter v3 is

```
Array
(
    [0] => SELECT GET_LOCK('0ae383feca87611f9ef779f13ae5d3f3', 300) AS ci_session_lock
    [1] => SELECT `data`
FROM `ci_sessions_3`
WHERE `id` = '9sh99dhtp1i51t21g498gerhem4e6gl6'
    [2] => SELECT * FROM `tradelog` WHERE status=1
)
```

and the result of *$this->db->query_times* in codeigniter v3 is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.00015497207641602
    [1] => 0.0003199577331543
    [2] => 0.0003359317779541
)
```

Both array have same number of indexes because first array contains queries which is executed and second array contains these queries executed time.

I have a little problem which is to determine the query_time format to properly convert into seconds or in minutes.

### It'll be used like this

(*Ignore it if you're not interested how it will be used*)

I'll use it to record all my queries in *queries.log.txt* file in development Environment by hooking **LogQueryHook** class after post controller hooks in codeigniter.

Goto to *application/config/config.php* and change this

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
```

to this

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
        break;
    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
    default:
        $config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
        break;
}
```

so only in development you log all queries.

Now goto *application/config/hooks.php* to hook your LogQueryHook class after post system . Just copy paste this code.

```
$hook['post_system'][] = array(
    'class' => 'LogQueryHook',
    'function' => 'log_queries',
    'filename' => 'LogQueryHook.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Create a file name "LogQueryHook.php" in hooks folder in application folder.
It'll look like this *application\hooks\LogQueryHook.php*
Now paste this code to log every query with execution time took.

```
class LogQueryHook
{
    function log_queries()
    {
        $CI = &get_instance ();
        $times = $CI->db->query_times;
        $output = null;
        $queries = $CI->db->queries;
        $date_now = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa');

        /** Spaces are given for proper alignment of text */
        if (count ($queries) == 0) {
            $output .= $date_now . "        no queries\n";
        } else {
            foreach ($queries as $key => $query) {
                $took = round (doubleval ($times[$key]), 3);
                // I need to improve this line to record time properly
                // and I don't know in which format codeginiter is giving me time either its is seconds or miliseconds.
                $output .= $date_now . "        ===[took:{$took}]\n";
                $query = str_replace (array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\\r", "\\n", "\\r\\n"), "\n                             ", "                             " . $query);
                $output .= $query . "\n\n\n";
            }
        }

        $CI->load->helper ('file');
        if (!write_file (APPPATH . "/logs/queries.log.txt", $output, 'a+')) {
            log_message ('debug', 'Unable to write query the file');
        }
    }
}
```

After that run any page in development environment and all the queries will be recorded in *application\logs\queries.log.txt* file.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I have a little problem which is to determine the query_time format to properly convert into seconds or in minutes. I just don't know either it is in nanoseconds or microseconds or milliseconds or just in second because there is no documentation.

Comment: i don't understand it. 0.00015497207641602 means 0.00015497207641602 seconds. Whats your desired output ? ;)

Comment: are you sure its 0.00015497207641602 seconds it could be nanosecond or microseconds. I can't tell because there is no documentation.

Comment: yep i'm sure look @ https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php#L668 and take a look at the following code http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/42fe90bc437a1f49f17edfd451dab8cfc35e4f10 - its basically the same mechanism ;)

Comment: Thanks for the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query_time` will return seconds as an output `($time_end - $time_start)`.
Both these `$time_end` and `$time_start` uses `microtime` function [in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) with parameter set to true.
`microtime(TRUE)` : this returns seconds instead of micro seconds.